# C# Json to List

Tags: c#, json

I have a json object as follows:

```
"dnsNames": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": [
        "something.else.com",
        "something.com",
        "else.com"
      ]
    }
```

I'd like to read that into a `List<string>` the same way I can read it into a string (i.e. without creating a class for it):

```
JObject jsonParameters = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
string test = jsonParameters["parameters"]["dnsNames"]["defaultValue"].ToString();
```

Just unsure if that's possible or what the syntax for it might be.

Comment: You want to read `defaultValue` only into a `List<string>`?

Comment: Yes to get those 3 values into a list or string[]. I know I can just get all values into a string (as `string test` above) and split that but I'm assuming there's a nicer way (other than new object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Navigate the object structure as you see it `dnsNames.defaultValue` then convert that object to a given type (`List<string>` in our case):

```
var json =
  @"{""dnsNames"": {
  ""type"": ""array"",
  ""defaultValue"": [
    ""something.else.com"",
    ""something.com"",
    ""else.com""
  ]
}}";

var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var list = jObject["dnsNames"]["defaultValue"].ToObject<List<string>>();

// ?list
// Count = 3
// [0]: "something.else.com"
// [1]: "something.com"
// [2]: "else.com"
```

Comment: That's exactly it. Thank you kindly. Is there a way to drop the list variable back into the jobject after it was updated?

Comment: Yes, you can do it like this: jObject["dnsNames"]["defaultValue"] = JToken.FromObject(list)